# When there are some saved people for the first time?

Tags: matthew

> Matthew 1:21
>  And she will have a son, and you are to name him Jesus,
> for **he will save his people from their sins**

I've searched the internet by typing the title of this post, but it has no result where the article say about it.

What I mean in the question is at what "time-frame" there are some saved people for the first time?

If I put "when Jesus was born", to me it seems not fit.
If I put "during His ministry", I feel still not fit
So I'm left with : "soon after Jesus died on the cross".

Since I'm not sure, so I ask here.

Comment: The Gospel of Matthew documents many occurrences of faith healing, but we are told once during His Ministry that Jesus specifically declares the forgiveness of sins to one person - a Paralyzed Man [ Matthew 9:1-3 ] : “Take heart, son; your sins are forgiven.”

Answer (score 4):

Peter tells the 'strangers scattered' that :

> ... Christ has ... suffered for us ... who, his own self bare our sins in his own body on the tree. [1 Peter 2:24 KJV],

making it clear that sins were contained within Christ's own humanity, and that he suffered for them, personally, whilst being crucified.

Paul the apostle writes to the churches of Galatia, saying :

> ... our Lord Jesus Christ who gave himself for our sins ... [Galatians 1:4 KJV],

showing that His whole self was offered up in order for sins to be eradicated.

Paul also tells the church of God at Corinth :

> ... how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures [1 Corinthians 15:3 KJV],

again expressing the fact that in his sacrifice of himself, during death, he gave himself for the sins of others.

The writer to the Hebrews makes another thing clear :

> ... when he had, by himself, purged our sins, sat down on the right hand of the Majesty on high [Hebrews 1:3 KJV],

that sins were purged and gone by the time Jesus Christ rose from the dead, was received up into heaven and sat down in the throne of God.

---

Having suffered and having effectively dealt with sins, He also brings the benefit of that in salvation to the recipient.

> ... For he (Christ Jesus v13) is our peace ... and came and preached peace to you which were afar off and to them that are nigh. [Ephesians 2:14,17 KJV].

If we walk in the light, says John, as he is in the light, we have fellowship one with another and the blood of Jesus Christ his Son cleanseth us from all sin. ... If we confess our sins [to the Father] he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness, 1 John 1:7,9 KJV.

Jesus Christ saves his people from their sins by giving himself (Gal 1:4) by baring them in is body on the tree (1 Pe 2:4) by dying (1 Co 15:3).

Thereafter, his blood is 'sprinkled' that is to say the experience of what he suffered is made known by the work of the Holy Spirit, bringing salvation (Titus 2:11).

> Elect according to the foreknowledge of God the father through sanctification of the Spirit unto obedience and ***sprinkling of the blood of Jesus Christ*** : Grace unto you, and peace, be multiplied. [1 Peter 1:2 KJV]

Paul uses the expression, justified by his blood, in Romans 5:9 and I would say, myself, that this refers to both the shed blood of Christ (when the lance was thrust into his side) ***and*** to the blood of sprinkling. Redemption occurred at Golgotha but justification is *completed* when the righteousness of God is viewed, by God, to the account of the believer.

Comment: You wrote : _"that sins were purged and gone by the time Jesus Christ rose from the dead"_. Am I correct to conclude the time-frame when there are some saved people for the first time was by the time Jesus rose from the dead? I mean, at the time Jesus died, there were no saved people yet, but three days later. Thank you for your answer, Nigel.

Answer (score 0):

When did Jesus save His people from their sins?

Technically from a historical and legal perspective, it happened in

> John 19:30
> When he had received the drink, Jesus said, "**It is finished**." With that, he bowed his head and gave up his spirit.

What I mean in the question is at what "time-frame" there are some saved people for the first time?

God is not bound by time or history.

> Mark 12:27
> He is not the God of the dead, but of the living.

We see the appearance of Moses and Elijah in

> Matthew 17:1 After six days Jesus took with him Peter, James and John the brother of James, and led them up a high mountain by themselves. 2There he was transfigured before them. His face shone like the sun, and his clothes became as white as the light. 3Just then there appeared before them **Moses and Elijah, talking with Jesus**.

Answer (score 0):

The Bible is very clear about this:

> Matt 1:21 - And she will have a son, and you are to name him Jesus,
> for he will save his people from their sins

Thus, the mission of Jesus was to **save** and at his birther, this was still future according to the tense of the above verb.  The earthly part of the mission was complete when Jesus said it was -

> John 19:30 - When he had received the drink, Jesus said, "It is
> finished." With that, he bowed his head and gave up his spirit.

Paul makes this clear as well:

> Rom 3:23-26 - for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God,
> and are justified freely by His grace through the redemption that is
> in Christ Jesus.  **God presented Him as the atoning sacrifice through
> faith in His blood**, in order to demonstrate His righteousness,
> because in His forbearance He had passed over the sins committed
> beforehand. He did this to demonstrate His righteousness at the
> present time, **so as to be just and to justify the one who has faith
> in Jesus.**

> Rom 5:9, 10 - Therefore, since we have now been **justified by His
> blood**, how much more shall we be saved from wrath through Him! For
> if, when we were enemies of God, we were reconciled to Him through the
> death of His Son, how much more, having been reconciled, shall we be
> saved through His life!

> 1 John 2:2 - He Himself is the **atoning sacrifice** [= expiation or
> propitiation] for our sins, and not only for ours but also for the
> sins of the whole world.

This is the central plank of Christian teaching as recorded several times in the NT and formulated in early creeds such as:

> 1 Cor 15:3, 4 - For what I received I passed on to you as of first
> importance: that Christ **died for our sins** according to the
> Scriptures, that He was buried, that He was raised on the third day
> according to the Scriptures,

The expiation, atonement and forgiveness that Jesus graciously, and by His own initiative, provided on the cross is called the great divine exchange:

- 2 Cor 5:21, God made him who had no sin to be sin for us, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God.
- Gal 1:4, who gave himself for our sins to rescue us from the present evil age, according to the will of our God and Father.
- Isa 53:4, 5, Surely He took on our infirmities and carried our sorrows; yet we considered Him stricken by God, struck down and afflicted.  But He was pierced for our transgressions, He was crushed for our iniquities; the punishment that brought us peace was upon Him, and by His stripes we are healed.

That is, Jesus was treated as we deserve so that we can be treated as He deserved.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, I’ll take the ‘left field’ position...

Jesus died before the earth was formed ... Sin was ‘dealt with’ before **Genesis 1:1**.

**REV 13:8** [snip] *slain from the foundation of the world.*

The physical manifestation was at the cross, but, that doesn’t mean that’s when it happened. The Bible is the authority. We also have it prophesied in **GEN 3:15**.

Now to ‘the proof’. Something that ‘happens’ in the ‘spiritual realm’ is real. God told Adam that he would die the day he ate from the tree. Did he? Yes! But, he didn’t ‘die’ physically until he was 930 years old. So Jesus died in the ‘spiritual realm’ before the foundation of the earth. God’s Word says so.

So, to **your question** ‘*at what "time-frame" there are some saved people for the first time?*’ Adam was saved, as was Abraham, etc. But just like with eating from the tree, the manifestation of anyone being saved may come later, but nevertheless, they are/were saved, right from the start.

Comment: This idea is not without merit - I understand what you are saying but it would help your case if your could marshal a little more evidence.

Comment: @dave Well, sort of... God saved from sin as you say, but He did it through Jesus once he was crucified - which is the context of the Q. The *process* of salvation commenced before the RE-creation of Gen, and was finalised at the cross. Yet, it is also true that what God says will be - already IS.

Comment: @Dottard (and user48152) Seems to me most took ‘saved’ as meaning ‘born again’. Jesus, John the Baptist, the disciples, were ‘getting people saved’ before He went to the cross. Be a little difficult to try and explain that (for example) Abraham wasn’t saved when he died.

Comment: @Dave - That is why this whole concept of the atonement involves several aspects, namely, (1) God's decision to save before the foundation of the world, (2) the actual propitiation at the cross which the Bible emphasizes, (3) the acceptance of of that salvation by the individual, (4) the resurrection of the individual and glorification into heaven.  Should we deal with all these other aspects as well?

Comment: @Dave, in other words, did you mean that before the creation all of not yet created people are already in heaven and hell ?

Comment: @karma No. I do not believe in predestination. I am saying that salvation was available right from the ‘start’. Man has always had ‘means’ by which to be ‘saved’.

Comment: @Dave, sorry for my limited English ... what did you mean with _"they are/were saved, right from the start"_ ?

Comment: @karma Ahhh my mistake.   I see how my reference to ‘they’ could be taken in a far broader sense. By ‘they’ I was referring back to Adam and Abraham from a few sentences earlier. And that they were saved by their choice, (belief) that they enacted (But this was not decided before they were ‘born’)